# gtk.Toolbar deprecation warning fix

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, pygtk

So I've been using a `gtk.Toolbar` object for a while and was using the `append_item` method but was getting a deprecation warning. So I tried the `insert_item` method and still got a deprecation warning. So I tried creating a `gtk.ToolButto`n separately and then using the `insert` method to add it which got rid of the warning but now the toolbar (which was working perfectly fine before) is not showing up at all and no errors are produced!!! What is the proper way to do this because I have no idea anymore?

Here is some example code. I have 3 toolbars so I'm only posting the 1 that has only 1 button on it.

```
    vBox = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
    vBox.set_size_request(400,500)
    vBox.set_border_width(2)
    vBox.show()
    prefWin.add(vBox)

    bar = gtk.Toolbar()
    bar.show()
    vBoxFix = gtk.VBox(False,0)
    vBoxFix.pack_end(bar,False,False,0)
    vBoxFix.show()
    vBox.pack_end(vBoxFix,False,False,0)

    closeButt =gtk.ToolButton(None,'Close')
    closeButt.connect('clicked',self.notYet)
    closeButt.show()
    bar.insert(closeButt,0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `insert` method appears to be the correct one.  Did you make sure to `show` the toolbar somewhere, perhaps by using the `show_all` method of the parent?  And if so, did you pack the toolbar into a box in the window, to make sure that the window itself actually *is* an ancestor of the toolbar?

Comment: I did all of the above (as you can see in the code example I added), and I do get a toolbar but there are no buttons on it. On another toolbar that has more buttons (all using the old method) I tried changing only the first button to this method and all the buttons and widgets on it disappeared.

Comment: I added some scaffolding and got your example to work with a couple of modifications: see http://pastebin.com/hhyT00u2 .  Your main problems seem to be that you might have been doing stuff in the wrong order, and/or you had to set a style for the toolbar before using in that way.

Comment: It did seem to be a matter of order. I also tried without using the stock button (since I have some others that aren't stock) and got it to work. I had it working the other way before so I didn't think the order was an issue. Thanks.